# How can I set up django not to use in-memory database during unittest?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, sqlite

django sets up a database in memory for testing if the database engine selected is sqlite3. However, I need the database to be on the filesystem. How can I change the settings to make this possible?

Comment: Why do you need the db on the filesystem? I wouldn't recommend using SQLite for anything serious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database):

> By default the test databases get their names by prepending test_ to
>   the value of the NAME settings for the databases defined in DATABASES.
>   **When using the SQLite database engine the tests will by default use an
>   in-memory database** (i.e., the database will be created in memory,
>   bypassing the filesystem entirely!). **If you want to use a different
>   database name, specify NAME in the TEST dictionary for any given
>   database in DATABASES**.

Specify the `NAME` key in the [`TEST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-TEST) dictionary:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        ...
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': '/path/to/the/db/file'
        }
    }
}
```

Note that for Django 1.6 and below, you should set `TEST_NAME` instead:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        ...
        'TEST_NAME': '/path/to/the/db/file'
    }
}
```